# How to improve geographical diversification?

Tags: investing, etf, asset-allocation, diversification

Recently realised on my investments' geo distribution map that they are largely (~83%) in NA/EU.

[image: Asset distribution showing 63% allocated in NA, 15% in EU and 5% in UK]

Given this, **should I diversify by region further? What kind of ETFs/funds in general avoid NA/EU?**

Note that

- these investments are mainly index funds so they're already diversified, just not geographically
- South America/Middle East/Asia are probably higher risk than the current regions - that's OK
- this is *not* about "developing" regions, as there are several "developed" countries in those regions

Vanguard ETFs preferred, as that's what I'm currently using (provided they exist - could find e.g. EX-UK/US funds but nothing targeting east EU + Asia/South of world)

Comment: VWO description is "Invests in stocks of companies located in emerging markets around the world, such as China, Brazil, Taiwan, and South Africa.", and [this page](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/portfolio/vwo) shows coverage of Middle East, Eastern Europe, South America, SE Asia.  Not much Africa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index funds may be more geographically diversified than you think, since many companies that are *based* in the US (for example) actually derive a lot of their business from emerging markets. One admittedly extreme example is [Coca-Cola](https://www.strategy-business.com/article/00093?gko=6397d):

> Coca-Cola is one of the most globally active international companies, deriving 80 percent of its sales from outside the U.S.

Yes, companies based in region A are affected by economic conditions in that region, especially if economic conditions affect how easily they can raise funds, access credit, etc. However, if there is a downturn in the US, Coca-Cola wouldn't be as affected as other companies because much of their revenue is drawn from consumers outside the US.

(I'm just using the US as an example here; the same logic applies to companies based in the EU, China, etc. but deriving portions of their revenue from other markets)

---

I readily admit that this answer may not be the most satisfying as data on the share of a company's income earned in each market is not always easy to find. It doesn't necessarily show up in a standardized way in [public financial statements](https://www.coca-colacompany.com/content/dam/journey/us/en/private/fileassets/pdf/investors/2019/coca-cola-2019-q1-earnings-release.pdf), so calculating the geographic diversification for an entire ETF can be daunting.